# What does $p_b \propto ρ^n _b $ mean

Tags: notation, fluid-dynamics

$p_b \propto ρ^n _b $, in fluid mechanics, where $p_b$ is the pressure inside a bubble and $\rho$ is the density.

What does that symbol looking like alpha mean?

Comment: Probably:  "directly proportional".  so $X ∝ Y$ means there exists a constant $\lambda$ such that $X=\lambda Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that $p_b$ is [directly proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_%28mathematics%29) to $ρ^n _b$.

i.e. $p_b = C\rho_b^n$, for some constant $C$ (to be determined).